# Not receiving data in a NestJS microservice

Tags: sockets, nestjs, microservices

I'm trying to create a NestJS microservice that can listen for data on a specific port.  Following the instructions from [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics), I have the following for `main.ts`:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { MicroserviceOptions, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

const HOST = '127.0.0.1';
const PORT = 31123;

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    AppModule,
    {
      transport: Transport.TCP,
      options: {
        host: HOST,
        port: PORT
      }
    },
  );
  await app.listen();
}
bootstrap();
```

My `app.controller.ts` looks like:

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MessagePattern } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }

  @MessagePattern('hello')
  dataHandler(data: string) {
    console.log(`Received: ${data}`);
  }
}
```

I'm attempting to send data to the microservice via a Python script, running on the same computer:

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 31123

someData = 'hello'

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
  s.connect((HOST, PORT))

  print(f'Sending: "{someData}"')
  encodedString = someData.encode('utf8')
  s.sendall(bytearray(encodedString))
```

The data never gets through; the `log` message in the `dataHandler` function in the microservice never executes.  Am I specifying the message-pattern incorrectly, or are NestJS microservices not designed to handle raw TCP socket data?  I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964076/whats-a-valid-messagepattern-for-nestjs-mqtt-microservice) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291285/how-to-use-nestjs-redis-microservice/54293468#54293468), but those deal more with message broker situations.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who lands here looking for a solution, I found the solution to this from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60481672/tcp-server-using-nestjs)